# Keyup input not getting value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a small script so whenever the user inputs some text on the webpage it will get me the value instantly. Unfortunately the Keyup() JQUERY function is returning no value when I try to test it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keyup(function() {
        var command = $(this).val();
        alert(command);
    });
});
```

The alert shows no text what-so-ever and i'm unsure why?

Comment: Try this: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $(:input).keyup(function() {
        var command = $(this).val();
        alert(command);
    });
});`

Comment: I'm trying to attach it to the document because I don't want them to "have" to be typing into a text box in order to know what they're typing (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is `$(document)` which has no value.
You can get value only if your selector is any input.
If you want to get character type by user then try it as follow

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    var command = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    alert(command);
});
```

Comment: Works as I wanted it to. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input").keyup(function() {
            var command = $(this).val();
            alert(command);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <input type="text">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the snippet

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    var command = $(e.target).val()
    alert(command);
});
});
```

$(this) always remain where you are binding the event which is document in your case but e.target provides current element where you are using your event.

Comment: Same problem. Nothing is being returned in the alert();

Comment: this is just for all the input boxes. So you want to detect anything user is pressing on keyboard??

Answer (score -1):

1. There are various ways to fix it. It is like two way binding.
2. You can play with keyup/keydown events of jquery
3. Other wise you can prefer [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) which has built in functionality of two way binding.